OMC in openmeodica outputs incorrect parameters in csv file
I wrote an oms script, but I am not getting correct output described by my script. In the script I wanted to save parameters ("building_load.p", "grid.sou.S[1]", "generator.P") to a csv file, so I ran this script.
loadModel(Modelica,{"4.0.0"}); getErrorString();
loadFile("cert_mg_generation.mo"); getErrorString();
simulate(building, fileNamePrefix = "cert_mg_output", outputFormat = "csv", variableFilter ="building_load\.P|grid\.sou\.S[1]|generator\.P");getErrorString();


I however got these parameters instead: "building_load.P","solar_data.y[1]","generator.P". I am not sure why it saved "solar_data.y[1]" instead of "grid.sou.S[1]".  The file is named 'cert_mg_output_res.csv' as well instead of 'cert_mg_output.csv'. Attached is my .mo, and .mos file. Thank you for the help.
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1xwxYO4uB5J156m5X88K-YSN8Ko8XWyQH?usp=sharing

Does it work if you specify grid\.sou\.phi instead of grid\.sou\.S[1], i.e. by avoiding the brackets [ and ] in the filter expesssion? Should the brackets be escaped?

@tbeu Unfortunately, it does not work for me. I see how the brackets may cause problems, but why is S[1] replaced with phi. Also, I can also understand it not outputting grid.sou[1], but not why it is outputting solar_data.y[1]. Is it because one of the last lines of code was solar_data.y[1] connect(solar_data.y[1], generator.P) annotation(
Line(points = {{-68, 0}, {-50, 0}}, color = {0, 0, 127})); ?  Thank you for the help.

@tbeu Ignore my past comment it does work. I put /phi instead of /.phi
I am not sure how phi is  equivalent to S[1], but thank you for the help.
